# HDFS copyToLocalFile throws java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file

Tags: java, hdfs

I am trying to copy the file from HDFS to Local linux file system using Hadoop `FileSystem` class.

I have access to create folder in the path where i am trying to copy, i checked using `mkdir` command.

Also i tried using shell command `hadoop fs -copyToLocal hdfsFilePath localFilepath` it was working.

I am running this on YARN Cluster.
I tried below approaches, but i am getting the `java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/user` error.

**Error log:**

```
16/01/14 01:09:36 ERROR util.FileUtil: 
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /home/user (exists=false, cwd=file:/hdfs4/yarn/nm/usercache/user/appcache/application_1452126203792_8862/container_e2457_1452126203792_8862_01_000001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:442)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1939)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1915)
    at com.batch.util.FileUtil.copyToLocalFileSystem(FileUtil.java:66)
    at com.batch.dao.impl.DaoImpl.writeFile(DaoImpl.java:108)
    at com.batch.JobDriver.runJob(JobDriver.java:79)
    at com.batch.JobDriver.main(JobDriver.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
```

Actually i am passing `localFilePath` as `/home/user/test`, but i am getting the error like `failed to create file:/home/user`

```
fs.copyToLocalFile(hdfsFilePath, localFilePath);
fs.copyToLocalFile(false, hdfsFilePath, localFilePath, true);
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the full stack trace?

Comment: try `sudo hadoop fs -copyToLocal hdfsFilePath localFilepath`  may be your program is not having rights...

Comment: @Pranalee  how do i give access to program, i am running spark job using spark-submit command..

Comment: I'm not sure on how to do it... need to figure it out but meanwhile  can you try running program by giving another location, somewhere in your user / documents directory

Comment: I tried all the locations, the YARN cluster is secured one,i am not sure that is causing the issue.

Comment: try copying data to any other location but /home it is may be due to the user by which job is executing and the user where you are copying the data.

Comment: did you try to run all commands with root privileges?

Answer (score 2):

This week i faced the same thing, problem was that i was deploying the job in **cluster mode**, therefore the machine where the job was going to run did not have that directory created. Is it possible you are deploying the job in **cluster mode**? If so, try deploying it in **client mode** (the output directory has to exist though)

Comment: I will check this one, might be this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for this exact error, but maybe not from YARN:

I had this exact error when trying to run `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile` on my local (Mac) machine, with local FS configured using the `job.local.dir` attribute.

This was the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/User/yossiv/algo-resources/AWS/QuerySearchEngine.blacklistVersionFile (exists=false, cwd=file:/Users/yossiv/git/c2s-algo)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:928)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:806)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2066)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2035)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2011)
```

What fixed it was to change `job.local.dir` to be **under the current directory** , which is listed in the exception text after `cwd=`, In my case that's `/Users/yossiv/git/c2s-algo`.

Broke my head two days over this, hope this helps someone.

Comment: Ran into the same issue on cluster mode. Your solution would be great back then but now it seems to be deprecated property. I'm breaking my head now :)